# Is the Linux implementation of the system configuration "variable" ARG_MAX different from other system variables and is it POSIX compliant?

Tags: history, posix, limit

In the shell, as explained in this [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110282/cp-max-source-files-number-arguments-for-copy-utility) in the context of expansion, depending on the system, the maximum length of a command's argument is initially constrained by the kernel setup. The maximum value is revealed at runtime using the [`getconf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/getconf) command (see also [IEEE Std 1003.1, 2013 Edition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getconf.html)):

```
# getconf ARG_MAX
2097152
vs. value found in limits.h on my setup:
#define ARG_MAX       131072    /* # bytes of args + environ for exec() */
```

Indeed:

> The sysconf() call supplies a value that corresponds to the conditions
>   when the program was either compiled or executed, depending on the
>   implementation; the system() call to getconf always supplies a value
>   corresponding to conditions when the program is executed.

The manpages reference POSIX, from the prolog alluding the *POSIX Programmer's manual*, to the *description* itself:

> The value of each configuration variable shall be determined as if it
>   were obtained by calling the function from which it is defined to be
>   available by this volume of POSIX.1-2008 or by the System Interfaces
>   volume of POSIX.1-2008 (see the OPERANDS section). The value shall
>   reflect conditions in the current operating environment.

The basic variables which can be queried appear in the table for the `sysconf` function specification and there is more information about the values in the [`limits.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html) header documentation:

```
{ARG_MAX}
    Maximum length of argument to the exec functions including environment data.
    Minimum Acceptable Value: {_POSIX_ARG_MAX}
...(nb you cannot be POSIX compliant under a certain value...)
{_POSIX_ARG_MAX}
    Maximum length of argument to the exec functions including environment data.
    Value: 4 096
```

The `xargs --show-limits` command confirms some of this:

```
Your environment variables take up 3134 bytes
POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system): 2091970
POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): 4096
Maximum length of command we could actually use: 2088836
Size of command buffer we are actually using: 131072
```

[`sysconf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sysconf.html) was initially designed to find the system value for the PATH variable, then it was extended to other variables. Now, the *Open Group* documentation explores the rationale for having such a framework where applications can poll for system variables at runtime, and the related practical considerations about the baseline...:

> (...) If limited to the most restrictive values in the headers, such
>   applications would have to be prepared to accept the most limited
>   environments offered by the smallest microcomputers. Although this is
>   entirely portable, there was a consensus that they should be able to
>   take advantage of the facilities offered by large systems, without the
>   restrictions associated with source and object distributions.
>
> During the discussions of this feature, it was pointed out that it is
>   almost always possible for an application to discern what a value
>   might be at runtime by suitably testing the various functions
>   themselves. And, in any event, it could always be written to
>   adequately deal with error returns from the various functions. In the
>   end, it was felt that this imposed an unreasonable level of
>   complication and sophistication on the application developer.

...as well as the shortcomings of such a setup as it relates to some file variables with [`fpathconf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fpathconf.html):

> The pathconf() function was proposed immediately after the sysconf()
>   function when it was realized that some configurable values may differ
>   across file system, directory, or device boundaries.
>
> For example, {NAME_MAX} frequently changes between System V and
>   BSD-based file systems; System V uses a maximum of 14, BSD 255. On an
>   implementation that provides both types of file systems, an
>   application would be forced to limit all pathname components to 14
>   bytes, as this would be the value specified in  on such a
>   system.

So the intent was to relieve developers of some burden for the baseline while also acknowledging variety in the filesystems and generally enabling some customizing on different variants of the platform. The evolution of hardware, [Unix](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/) and related standards (C and POSIX) plays a role here.

**Questions:**

- The command `getconf` doesn't have a "list" option, and `set`, `printenv` or `export` don't show those variables. Is there a command which lists their value?
- Why facilities like `fpathconf` were seemingly built to introduce more flexibility, but only for PATH and file related system variables? Is it just because at that time getconf was only about PATH?
- What is the current Linux [implementation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html), and is it POSIX compliant? In the [linked Q](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110282/cp-max-source-files-number-arguments-for-copy-utility) there is reference in the answers to ARG_MAX varying with the stack size ("on Linux 3.11... a quarter of the limit set on the stack size, or 128kiB if that's less than 512kiB"):

  - What is the rationale for this?
  - Is this choice (1/4 of the stack size) a Linux specific implementation or just a feature on top of the basic implementation or did the historical UNIX implementation always yield basically that 1/4th of the stack size?
  - Are many other variables besides ARG_MAX a function of the *stack* size or similar resources or does the importance of this variable warrant a special treatment?
  - Practically, does one deliver a POSIX compliant Linux system/solution and there's configuration of the stack size limit for example to allow some application to go beyond the basic maximum spec if it scales up with the hardware or is it a practice to customize directly `limits.h` and compile for specific needs?
  - What is the difference for something like ARG_MAX between using `limits.h` vs. changing the variable at runtime with something like the [`ulimit -s`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) command vs. having the kernel manage it directly? In particular is the (low)value of that variable in my `limits.h` obsolete on Linux because of kernel changes i.e. has it been superseded?
- The command line supposedly has shell specific length restrictions which are not related to expansion and ARG_MAX; what are they in `bash`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard way to retrieve the list of configuration variables that are supported on a system. If you program for a given POSIX version, the list in that version of the POSIX specification is your reference list. On Linux, `getconf -a` lists all available variable.

[`fpathconf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fpathconf.html) isn't specific to PATH. It's about variables that are related to files, which are the ones that may vary from file to file.

Regarding `ARG_MAX` on Linux, the rationale for depending on the stack size is that the arguments end up on the stack, so there had better be enough room for them plus everything else that must fit. Most other implementations (including older versions of Linux) have a fixed size.

Most limits go together with resource availability, with different resources depending on the limit. For example, a process may be unable to open a file even if it has fewer than `OPEN_MAX` files open, if the system is out of memory that can be used for the file-related data.

Linux is POSIX-compliant on this point by default, so I don't know where you're getting at.

If you use `ulimit -s` to restrict the stack size to less than `ARG_MAX`, you're making the system no longer compliant. A POSIX system can typically be made non-compliant in any number of ways, including `PATH=/nowhere` (making all standard utilities unavailable) or `rm -rf /`.

The value of `ARG_MAX` in `limits.h` provides a minimum that applications can rely on. A POSIX-compliant system is allowed to let `execve` succeed even if the arguments exceed that size. The guarantee related to `ARG_MAX` is that if the arguments fit in that size then `execve` will not fail due `E2BIG`.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! The manpages don't show "-a"? What I was "getting at" in that part of the Q is that in my novice mind I thought you could 1-be non-compliant because you went too far up with the max despite clear reference to "minimum acceptable values" in the limits.h doc and 2-that ARG_MAX being updated for the resources at runtime, meant that limits.h was ignored on Linux; I aslo left out Q about vars at compile time. So the practical Q is just when you give a program to a client do you tell him change limits.h or set a specific stack limit. Neither, just works with what's there!