# How do I get a single total of lines with `wc -l`?

Tags: files, xargs, wc

I've added a git alias to give me the line counts of specific files in my history:

```
[alias]
lines = !lc() { git ls-files -z ${1} | xargs -0 wc -l; }; lc
```

However, `wc -l` is reporting multiple totals, such that if I have more than ~100k lines, it reports the total for them, then moves on. Here's an example:

#### <100k lines (desired output)

```
$ git lines \*.xslt
  46 packages/NUnit-2.5.10.11092/doc/files/Summary.xslt
 232 packages/NUnit-2.5.10.11092/samples/csharp/_UpgradeReport_Files/UpgradeReport.xslt
 278 total
```

#### >100k lines (had to pipe to `grep "total"`)

```
$ git lines \*.cs | grep "total"
 123569 total
 107700 total
 134796 total
 111411 total
  44600 total
```

How do I get a true total from `wc -l`, not a series of subtotals?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501402/why-does-the-wc-utility-generate-multiple-lines-with-total the problem is with `xargs`, not `wc`. I'm still interested in how to fix it, and I don't see a good solution in the answers.

Comment: Does your version of `wc` support the `--files0-from` option? Then you can do `{ git ls-files -z ${1} | wc -l --files0-from=- ; }`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I think that deserves to be an answer.

Comment: Nope. `wc: unrecognized option '--files0-from=-'`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this, and apologies for being obvious:

```
cat *.cs | wc -l
```

or, with git:

```
git ls-files -z ${1} | xargs -0 cat | wc -l
```

If you actually want the output to look like `wc` output, with both individual counts and a sum, you could use `awk` to add up the individual lines:

```
git ls-files -z ${1} | xargs -0 wc -l |
awk '/^[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+total$/{next}
     {total+=$1;print}
     END {print total,"total"}'
```

That won't be lined up as nicely as `wc` does it, in case that matters to you. To do that, you'd need to read the entire input and save it, computing the total, and then use the total to compute the field width before using that field width to print a formatted output of the remembered lines. Like home renovation projects, `awk` scripts are never ever really finished.

(Note to enthusiastic editors: the regular expression in the first `awk` condition is in case there is a file whose name starts with "total" and a space; otherwise, the condition could have been the much simpler `$2 == "total"`.)

Comment: That does work, but it outputs the total only (`git ls-files -z ${1} | xargs -0 cat | wc -l`). However, I'm missing the per-file line count that wc -l provides like in my first example above. Any way to get the best of both worlds here?

Comment: Or, if that's too difficult, how about a switch such that if it would break it up: just give the total, if it would not, give the normal wc per-file with a total output?

Comment: @Ehryk: you could just do it twice, once the way you were doing it with `grep -v` to drop the total lines, and once the way I suggest to get the total total. Or you could try the awk solution in the edited answer,

Comment: +1: "Like home renovation projects, awk scripts are never ever really finished."

Comment: That worked like a charm. My final result: `git ls-files -z ${1} | xargs -0 wc -l | awk '/^[[:space:]]*[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+total$/{next} {total+=$1;print} END {print "\n Total:",total,"lines"}'`

Comment: I've marked yours as the answer, but just out of curiosity; is there any way to group the output of ls-files into the subdirectories from the current directory, so that `wc -l` returns the total for a given file type for each subdirectory (no recursion), then the total total?

Comment: @ehryk: There is always a way of doing things if you can precisely define what the thing you want to do is, which is why awk scripts are never ever really finished. One important fact to help you with grouping: `/` is not a legal character in a filepath segment, so the last `/` in a path is always the end of the directory part. There is never any need to interpret quotes or escape characters.

Comment: I don't really know where do begin. What I'd want to have would be:
Input: `git lines \*.cs`
Output `  481 / \n  234 Directory1/ \n 5212 Directory2/ \n Total: 5927 lines `

Answer (score 7):

If you're running Linux, your `wc` probably comes from GNU Coreutils and has a `--files0-from` option to read a file (or stdin) containing an arbitrarily long list of NUL-terminated names of file to count. The [GNU Coreutils wc documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/wc-invocation.html) says "This is useful when the list of file names is so long that it may exceed a command line length limitation.  In such cases, running wc via xargs is undesirable because it splits the list into pieces and makes wc print a total for each sublist rather than for the entire list."

So try this:

```
lc() { git ls-files -z ${1} | wc -l --files0-from=- ; }
```

Edit:
Since your `wc` is from the last millennium and doesn't have that option, here is a more portable solution, assuming you have `awk` and do not have any files named "total". It will filter the output of `wc`, omitting any `total` lines and instead summing them up and printing out the grand total at the end.

One thing I do not know is whether the `git` alias implementation will have problems with the `$1` and `$2` inside single quotes, which need to be passed unchanged to `awk`.

```
lc() {
  git ls-files -z ${1} |
  xargs -0 wc -l |
  awk 'BEGIN { total=0; } { if (NF==2 && $2 == "total") total += $1; else print; } END { print total, "total"; }' ;
}
```

Comment: I am not running linux, it's in the git bash prompt of Git for Windows http://msysgit.github.io/ (msysgit).

Comment: OK. So the `xargs` and `wc` you're running are from Cygwin? Can you paste the output of `wc --version` ?

Comment: They're not from a full cygwin install: `$ wc --version
wc (GNU textutils) 2.0
Written by Paul Rubin and David MacKenzie.

Copyright (C) 1999 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`

Comment: It's a full on windows executable, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\wc.exe`

Comment: @Ehryk Msysgit is a port of the Linux tools, but it tends to have old versions, so it may not have `--files0-from`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is `xargs` which is splitting the command into multiple runs, so `wc` is reporting the total for each time. You have a few options, you could keep things the way they are and parse the `wc` output:

```
git ls-files -z ${1} | xargs -0 wc -l | awk '/total/{k+=$1}END{print k,"total"}';
```

You could cat the files:

```
git ls-files -z ${1} | xargs -0 cat | wc -l
```

Or you could skip `xargs` altogether (adapted from [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)):

```
unset files i; while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' name; do 
 files[i++]="$name"; 
done < <(git ls-files -z ${1} ) && wc -l "${files[@]}"
```

That will break if your list of files is longer than [ARG_MAX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/110282/22222) though.

Answer (score -1):

```
j=0; for i in *.php *.js *.css; do let j+=`wc -l $i | awk {'print $1'}`; done; echo $j;
```