# Display file using Dialog

Tags: files, dialog

I have a file on disk which contains some text I want to display on the screen. You can do it like this:

```
dialog --yesno "`cat FILE`" 10 100
```

However, I'm concerned that if `FILE` becomes large, I'm likely to exceed the command length limits of the shell. Is there some other way to accomplish this task?

I want to display the contents of the file so the user can scroll through it (if it's *really* long), and then select what to do next. (I've relabelled the "yes" and "no" buttons to something more meaningful.) Presumably trying to pipe six pages of text through the command line like this is going to break.

Comment: What exactly is the task you are trying to accomplish? Are you trying to ensure the file does not exceed the capacity of dialog to display? Or are you seeking an alternative to dialog which will display an arbitrarily long amount of text? Would `--textbox file height width` work or do you need the user to agree to a large amount of text? Or what?

Comment: The command length is pretty damn long, will this ever be a problem?

Comment: I was under the impression that the command line is limited to 255 characters. The text _could_ end up being larger than that.

Comment: According to man: `--max-input size
Limit input strings to the given size. If not specified, the limit is 2048.`. I don't know if there is a limit for Bash. I've certainly never hit it.

Comment: OK, so that's significantly higher that I had expected. It still feels somehow "wrong" to be sending this much data via command arguments, rather than through a pipe or a file or something... Is there maybe some way to use the `--file` option?

Comment: @awk_FTW there is no limit for `bash` - the limit is imposed by the kernel, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120642/what-defines-the-maximum-size-for-a-command-single-argument. If the command is a `bash` built-in there is no limit.

Comment: `--textbox` takes a file as an argument. Have you tried putting the arguments in a file? `The "--file" option tells dialog to read parameters from the file named as its value.

dialog --file parameterfile`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the man page for this there does seem to be any way to avoid passing the text as an argument - there appears to be no way to pipe the data in or have `dialog` read directly from the file. However, you could limit the size of the argument using `head`. On most Linux systems the maximum size for a single argument is 32KiB, so you could do:

```
dialog --max-input 32768 --yesno "$(head -c 32K FILE)" 10 100
```

The maximum size for a single argument is defined by `MAX_ARG_STRLEN` which you will find in `/usr/include/linux/binfmts.h` if you have kernel headers installed. Usually the value is `PAGE_SIZE * 32` where `PAGE_SIZE` is usually 1KiB (see `/usr/include/linux/a.out.h`).

Of course these values can be completely reconfigured. Moreover `MAX_ARG_STRLEN` is Linux specific and was introduced in Linux 2.6.23. For more information about what the limits actually are, please see [What defines the maximum size for a command single argument?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120642/what-defines-the-maximum-size-for-a-command-single-argument).

#### Update

Oops, you can actually use the `--file` argument for this. It looks like you can do something like (without having tested):

```
{
  echo -n \"
  sed 's/"/\"/' FILE
  echo -n \"
} | dialog --yesno --file '&1' 10 100
```

No need for the `sed` if you know there are no quotes in the file. Or alternatively just put everything you need in the file (quotes, `--yesno` and all) and simply do:

```
dialog --file FILE
```

Comment: Dumping everything to a file solves this nicely.