# How much arguments can I pass to command?

Tags: command-line

Is there any limit of arguments that could be passed to C/C++, Python, Bash etc. program? Practical usage: pass bitmap data from/to C++ to/from Python program via arguments.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846263/maximum-length-of-command-line-argument-that-can-be-passed-to-sqlplus-from-lin

Comment: Also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120642/what-defines-the-maximum-size-for-a-command-single-argument

Comment: Using a stream (e.g., standard input) would be the normal way to do this.