# Argument list too long

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, arguments

I'm trying to enter a command with VERY big argument (1 MB in size), but it says "Argument list too long." How can I enter that argument?

OS: Linux Ubuntu

Comment: Depends on the OS.

Comment: @ilkkachu Linux Ubuntu

Comment: Oh, right, a _single_ big argument. Linux has a fixed limit for that, so you can't go over it without recompiling the kernel. See: [What defines the maximum size for a command single argument?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120642/170373)

Comment: What command are you attempting to use?

Comment: 1MB isn't very big, though it's bigger than `ARG_MAX` on my macOS Sierra (`262144`).  On Ubuntu 16.04, it seems to be larger: `docker run --rm ubuntu:latest getconf ARG_MAX` produces `2097152` for me, so you should be able to pass 1MB of argument string on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no way to pass an argument between executables if it is larger than the kernel's `ARG_MAX` limit.

If you have a *list of* arguments which is too long, splitting it up into smaller pieces can be done e.g. with `xargs`. This runs the command as many times as necessary, supplying as many arguments as will fit.

The syntax is `xargs command <file`. If you omit `command`, it displays its arguments, like `echo`.

As a demo,

```
xargs -n 4 </etc/motd
```

will print the first four tokens on one line (first invocation), the next four through another, etc. (The `-n` argument sets a maximum number of arguments, so this doesn't use the `ARG_MAX` limit at all.)

If the command you want to run has side effects which are undesirable, this might not work. For example, if the `command` will overwrite any previously existing `./a.out` file, you will obviously be left with the results from just the last run after it finishes.

If you can configure or modify `command` so it reads a file, or standard input, instead of a command-line argument, that will work around the restriction. A file or stream can be much larger than `ARG_MAX`, and often is.