# cat a very large number of files together in correct order

Tags: files, find, cat, brace-expansion

I have about 15,000 files that are named `file_1.pdb`, `file_2.pdb`, etc. I can cat about a few thousand of these in order by doing:

```
cat file_{1..2000}.pdb >> file_all.pdb
```

However, if I do this for 15,000 files, I get the error

```
-bash: /bin/cat: Argument list too long
```

I have seen this problem being solved by doing `find . -name xx -exec xx` but this wouldn't preserve the order with which the files are joined. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the tenth file named as? (Or any file with more than a single digit numbered ordering.)

Comment: I (now) have 15,000 of these files in a directory and your `cat file_{1..15000}.pdb` construct works fine for me.

Comment: depends on the system what the limit is. `getconf ARG_MAX` should tell.

Comment: Consider changing your question to "thousands of " or "a very large number of" files.  Might make the question easier to find for other people with a similar problem.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Using `find`, `sort` and `xargs`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'file_*.pdb' -print0 |
sort -zV |
xargs -0 cat >all.pdb
```

The `find` command finds all relevant files, then prints their pathnames out to `sort` that does a "version sort" to get them in the right order (if the numbers in the filenames had been zero-filled to a fixed width we would not have needed `-V`). `xargs` takes this list of sorted pathnames and runs `cat` on these in as large batches as possible.

This should work even if the filenames contains strange characters such as newlines and spaces.  We use `-print0` with `find` to give `sort` nul-terminated names to sort, and `sort` handles these using `-z`.  `xargs` too reads nul-terminated names with its `-0` flag.

Note that I'm writing the result to a file whose name does not match the pattern `file_*.pdb`.

---

The above solution uses some non-standard flags for some utilities.  These are supported by the GNU implementation of these utilities and at least by the OpenBSD and the macOS implementation.

The non-standard flags used are

- `-maxdepth 1`, to make `find` only enter the top-most directory but no subdirectories. POSIXly, use `find . ! -name . -prune ...`
- `-print0`, to make `find` output nul-terminated pathnames (this was considered by POSIX but rejected).  One could use `-exec printf '%s\0' {} +` instead.
- `-z`, to make `sort` take nul-terminated records. There is no POSIX equivalence.
- `-V`, to make `sort` sort e.g. `200` after `3`.  There is no POSIX equivalence, but could be replaced by a numeric sort on specific parts of the filename if the filenames have a fixed prefix.
- `-0`, to make `xargs` read nul-terminated records. There is no POSIX equivalence.  POSIXly, one would need to quote the file names in a format recognised by `xargs`.

If the pathnames are well behaved, and if the directory structure is flat (no subdirectories), then one could make do without these flags, except for `-V` with `sort`.

Comment: You don't need nonstandard null termination for this.  These filenames are exceedingly boring and the POSIX tools are entirely capable of handling then.

Comment: You could also write this more succinctly with the asker’s specification as `printf ‘file_%d.pdb\0’ {1..15000} | xargs -0 cat`, or even with Kevin’s point, `echo file_{1..15000}.pdb | xargs cat`. The `find` solution has considerably more overhead since it has to search the file system for those files, but it is more useful when some of the files may not exist.

Comment: It might be worth deconstructing the third line, since the last `> all.pdb` seems (incorrectly) to be attached to the `cat`, which would be a problem.

Comment: @Kevin while what you are saying is true, it's arguably better to have an answer that applies in more general circumstances.  Of the next thousand people that have this question, it's likely that some of them will have spaces or whatever in their file names.

Comment: @chrylis A redirection is never part of a command's arguments, and it's `xargs` rather than `cat` that is redirected (each `cat` invocation will use `xargs` standard output). If we had said `xargs -0 sh -c 'cat >all.pdb'` then it would have made sense to use `>>` instead of `>`, if that's what you're hinting at.

Comment: @kojiro Yes, possibly. It's a matter of taste I suppose. I tend to want to work with the names in the directory rather than with constructed names that I don't even know exists. Also, my private view is that brace expansions are kinda ugly; `{1..15000}` will expand to all integers between 1 and 15000, which will use memory wastefully (about 80 KB worth of memory for a list just to iterate over).

Comment: POSIX sort doesn't support non-text input. `-t` is to separate fields, not records.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks. Yes, trying to process ass sorts of filenames on a _strictly_ POSIX system will probably need another solution.

Comment: I think it's better to use `sort -n` instead of `sort -V`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc It depends whether you need to sort the strings `file3`, `file200` and `file10` in the correct order or not. `sort -n` will _not_ sort these into the correct order.

Comment: It looks like `sort -n -k1.6` would work (for the original, `file_nnn` filenames, or `sort -n -k1.5` for the ones without the underscore).

Answer (score 14):

With `zsh` (where that `{1..15000}` operator comes from):

```
autoload zargs # best in ~/.zshrc
zargs file_{1..15000}.pdb -- cat > file_all.pdb
```

Or for all `file_<digits>.pdb` files in numerical order:

```
zargs file_<->.pdb(n) -- cat > file_all.pdb
```

(where `<x-y>` is a glob operator that matches on decimal numbers x to y. With no `x` nor `y`, it's any decimal number. Equivalent to `extendedglob`'s `[0-9]##` or `kshglob`'s `+([0-9])` (one or more digits)).

With `ksh93`, using its builtin `cat` command (so not affected by that limit of the `execve()` system call since there's no *execution*):

```
command /opt/ast/bin/cat file_{1..15000}.pdb > file_all.pdb
```

With `bash`/`zsh`/`ksh93` (which support `zsh`'s `{x..y}` and have `printf` builtin):

```
printf '%s\n' file_{1..15000}.pdb | xargs cat > file_all.pdb
```

On a GNU system or compatible, you could also use `seq`:

```
seq -f 'file_%.17g.pdb' 15000 | xargs cat > file_all.pdb
```

For the `xargs`-based solutions, special care would have to be taken for file names that contain blanks, single or double quotes or backslashes.

Like for `-It's a trickier filename - 12.pdb`, use:

```
seq -f "\"./-It's a trickier filename - %.17g.pdb\"" 15000 |
  xargs cat > file_all.pdb
```

Comment: The `seq -f | xarg cat > ` is the most elegant, and effective solution. (IMHO).

Comment: Check the trickier filename...  maybe  `'"./-It'\''s a trickier filename - %.17g.pdb"'` ?

Comment: @Hastur, oops! Yes, thanks, I've changed it to an alternative quoting syntax. Yours would work as well.

Answer (score 12):

A for loop is possible, and very simple.

```
for i in file_{1..15000}.pdb; do cat $i >> file_all.pdb; done
```

The downside is that you invoke `cat` a hell of a lot of times.  But if you can't remember exactly how to do the stuff with `find` and the invocation overhead isn't too bad in your situation, then it's worth keeping in mind.

Comment: I often add a ``echo $i;`` in the loop body as a "progress indicator"

Answer (score 3):

```
seq 1 15000 | awk '{print "file_"$0".dat"}' | xargs cat > file_all.pdb
```

Comment: awk can do seq's job here and seq can do awk's job: `seq -f file_%.10g.pdb 15000`. Note that `seq` is not a standard command.

Comment: Thanks Stéphane --  I think    `seq -f`    is a great way to do this; will remember that.

Answer (score 2):

## Premise

You shouldn't incur in that error for ***only*** 15k files with that specific name format <sup>[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846263/maximum-length-of-command-line-argument-that-can-be-passed-to-sqlplus-from-lin),[2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/120842/66388)]</sup>.

If you are running that expansion from another directory and you have to add the path to each file, the size of your command will be bigger, and of course it can occur.

**Solution** run the command from that directory.

```
(cd That/Directory ; cat file_{1..2000}.pdb >> file_all.pdb )
```

**Best Solution** If instead I guessed bad and you run it from the directory in which the files are...
IMHO the best solution is the [Stéphane Chazelas' ones](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/426755/66388):

```
seq -f 'file_%.17g.pdb' 15000 | xargs cat > file_all.pdb
```

with printf or seq; tested on 15k files with only their number inside pre-cached it is even the faster one (at present and except the OP one from the same directory in which the files are).

### Some words more

You should be able to pass to your shell command lines more long.
Your command line is 213914 characters long and contains 15003 *words*
`cat file_{1..15000}.pdb " > file_all.pdb" | wc`

...even adding 8 bytes for each word is  333 938 bytes (0.3M) far below from the 2097142 (2.1M) reported by `ARG_MAX` on a kernel 3.13.0 or the slightly smaller  2088232 reported as *"Maximum length of command we could actually use"* by `xargs --show-limits`

Give it a look on your system to the output of

```
getconf ARG_MAX
xargs --show-limits
```

### Laziness guided solution

In cases like this I  prefer to work with blocks even because usually come out a time efficient solution.
The logic (if any) is I'm far too lazy to write 1...1000 1001..2000 etc etc...
So I ask a script to do it for me.
Only after I've checked the output is correctness I redirect it to a script.

*... but Laziness is a state of mind*.
Since I'm allergic to `xargs` (I really should have used `xargs` here) and I do not want to check how to use it, I punctually finish to reinvent the wheel as in the examples below (tl;dr).

Note that since the file names are controlled (no spaces, newlines...) you can go easily with something like the script below.

### tl;dr

#### Version 1: pass as optional parameter the 1st file number, the last, the block size, the output file

```
#!/bin/bash
StartN=${1:-1}          # First file number
EndN=${2:-15000}        # Last file number
BlockN=${3:-100}        # files in a Block 
OutFile=${4:-"all.pdb"} # Output file name

CurrentStart=$StartN 
for i in $(seq $StartN $BlockN $EndN)
do 
  CurrentEnd=$i ;  
    cat $(seq -f file_%.17g.pdb $CurrentStart $CurrentEnd)  >> $OutFile;
  CurrentStart=$(( CurrentEnd + 1 )) 
done
# Here you may need to do a last iteration for the part cut from seq
[[ $EndN -ge $CurrentStart ]] && 
    cat $(seq -f file_%.17g.pdb $CurrentStart $EndN)  >> $OutFile;
```

#### Version 2

Calling bash for the expansion (a bit slower in my tests ~20%).

```
#!/bin/bash
StartN=${1:-1}          # First file number
EndN=${2:-15000}        # Last file number
BlockN=${3:-100}        # files in a Block 
OutFile=${4:-"all.pdb"} # Output file name

CurrentStart=$StartN 
for i in $(seq $StartN $BlockN $EndN)
do 
  CurrentEnd=$i ;
    echo  cat file_{$CurrentStart..$CurrentEnd}.pdb | /bin/bash  >> $OutFile;
  CurrentStart=$(( CurrentEnd + 1 )) 
done
# Here you may need to do a last iteration for the part cut from seq
[[ $EndN -ge $CurrentStart ]] && 
    echo  cat file_{$CurrentStart..$EndN}.pdb | /bin/bash  >> $OutFile;
```

Of course you can go forward and get completely rid of `seq` <sup>[[3](https://linux.die.net/man/1/seq)]</sup> (from coreutils) and work directly with the variables in bash, or use python, or compile a c program to do it <sup>[[4](https://sites.google.com/site/tfsidc/linux-tricks/processing-a-large-number-of-files)]</sup>...

Comment: Note that `%g` is short for `%.6g`. It would represent 1,000,000 as 1e+06 for instance.

Comment: Really lazy people use the tools designed for the task of working around that E2BIG limitation like `xargs`, zsh's `zargs` or `ksh93`'s `command -x`.

Comment: `seq` is not a bash builtin, it's a command from GNU coreutils. `seq -f %g 1000000 1000000` outputs 1e+06 even in the latest version of coreutils.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas _Laziness is a state of mind._ Strange to say  but I feel more cosy when I can see (and visually check the output of a serialized command) and only then redirect to the execution.  That construction give me to think less than `xarg`... but I understand it is personal and maybe related only to me.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Gotcha, right... Fixed. Thanks. I tested only with the 15k files given by the OP, my bad.

Comment: @Hastur, while you're right that those 15k files might very well fit in a command line of a modern Linux system, do note that _they never said they were running Linux_. There are other systems too, and e.g. the Mac I'm on appears to have the limit at 256k. Which is more than those 213898 bytes you mention, but note that there's some per-argument overhead too (at least the size of a pointer, so probably 4 or 8 bytes)

Comment: @ilkkachu I mainly wanted to emphasize the fact that this error may occur just because you choose a different location from which to run your command. Let's see: `touch {1..146542}` is the upper number that did not throw that error on this particular system...  so  `echo touch {1..146542}  |wc` output gives me 914695 characters and 146543 words (of course)... mumble... the length of the command is 5+1 space... mumble mumble... (2097142 - 914695 -6) /  146542 ... mumble something more than 8... so 8 bytes for each parameter... Wow I think I just found out I've a 64bit system! `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it could be

```
(cat file_{1..499}.pdb; cat file_{500..999}.pdb; cat file_{1000..1499}.pdb; cat file_{1500..2000}.pdb) >> file_all.pdb
```