# Sort file array list in bash by date and bypass argument limit

Tags: bash, shell-script, sort, array, bash-array

So, I have a file array list in a bash shell, and I want to sort all the files in the array by the date modified, starting with the oldest being the first one in the array. However, I don't want to sort and modify the original array, and instead want to have the sorted result be in a different array. I saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575507/sort-list-of-files-by-date-in-bash) in which I tried the following command, although I modified it since the array was a variable and not a file.

```
new_array=( $(ls -t $(printf '%s\n' "${array_list[@]}")) )
```

However, the array is so big that ls reports the argument list is "too long"

Is there another way I can sort the main array by the modified date, starting with the oldest file at the beginning, and save the results to a different array?

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers.

Answer (score 3):

With newer versions of GNU `ls` and `bash`, you can do:

```
readarray -td '' new_array < <(
  ls --zero -dt -- "${array_list[@]}")
```

That doesn't bypass the `execve()` limit on the length of arguments+environment  though as we *are* executing `ls` with that list of arguments. You could pass that list to a function or the builtin `printf` which are not executed via `execve()` to feed that into a command that can read the list from stdin instead of as arguments.

With recent versions of GNU `find`  (and GNU `sort` and `cut`):

```
print0() { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\0' "$@"; }
readarray -td '' new_array < <(
  print0 "${array_list[@]}" |
    find -files0-from - -prune -printf '%T@\t%p\0' |
      sort -rzn |
      cut -zf2 -)
```

Or  with GNU `stat` and assuming none of the array elements are `-`:

```
print0() { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\0' "$@"; }
readarray -td '' new_array < <(
  print0 "${array_list[@]}" |
    xargs -r0 stat --printf='%.Y\t%n\0' --
      sort -rzn |
      cut -zf2 -)
```

`zsh` has a `stat` builtin (which predates the GNU one). So you can do it directly there with something like:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
typeset -A mtime
stat -nLA mtime -F %s%9. +mtime -- $array_list
new_array=( /(Ne['reply=($array_list)']nOe['REPLY=$mtime[$REPLY]']) )
```

Here building a `$mtime` `A`ssociative array to map files to their mtime, and sorting the list using the `Oe` glob qualifier with `n` (for numerical).

Comment: @GillesQuénot, the `--` is not needed in `printf -- '%s\0' "$@"` as the format doesn't start with `-` and no `printf` implementation is dumb enough to accept options after non-options (like the format here). It would be needed with some `printf` implementations in `printf -- '- %s' *.txt` or in `printf -- "$format" "$@"` where we don't know whether `$format` may start with `-` or not. It's needed in zsh's `print` equivalent: `print -rN -- "$@"` (where omitting it would even introduce a command injection vulnerability)

Answer (score 1):

Using a [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) one liner and `readarray`:

```
readarray -td '' new_array < <( 
    perl -l0e '
        print join "\0",
        sort { -M $a <=> -M $b }
        grep -f, @ARGV
    '  -- "${array_list[@]}"
)
```

Credits to [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/736231/sort-file-array-list-in-bash-by-date-and-bypass-argument-limit/736240?noredirect=1#comment1397877_736240) for `readarray`

Comment: Only `zsh` can do `IFS=$'\0'`. In bash, that's the same as `IFS=`, so no splitting. Also, in bash, unquoted  `$(...)` does splitting

Comment: In bash, use `readarray -td '' x < <(perl -l0 -e 'print for sort...' -- "${y[@]}"` (also note the `--` to avoid command injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Post edited accordingly, thanks

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75513104/465183

Comment: this is [subject to ARG_MAX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120642/what-defines-the-maximum-size-for-a-command-single-argument) - it would be better to pipe into perl with `printf '%s\0'` (as in  
Stéphane's answer).  Also there's a reason why an earlier answer in the SO question you linked to uses `map` to build a hash to get the mtime for each filename - it's far cheaper to run `stat` (even perl's built-in stat function or `-M`) *once per filename* rather than *twice per comparison in `sort()`*.

Comment: e.g. something like: `readarray -d '' -t new_array < <(printf -- '%s\0' "${array_list[@]}" | perl -0e 'my %files = map { chomp; $_ => (stat($_))[9] } (<>); print join "\0", sort { $b{$_} <=> $a{$_} } keys %files; print "\0"')`.  Or use Stéphane's `print0` shell function in case `array_list` is empty.

Comment: or, without `chomp`-ing and `join` (which I was only using while testing to get newline separated output): `readarray -d '' -t new_array < <(printf -- '%s\0' "${array_list[@]}" | perl -0e 'my %hash = map { $_ => (stat($_))[9] } (<>); print sort { $a{$_} <=> $b{$_} } keys %hash') `