# Copy the n-largest files from a certain directory to the current one

Tags: pipe, directory, ls, cp

I am trying to copy five largest files from a certain directory to my `pwd`. Using `cp specific/directory$(ls -S specific/directory | head -n) ./` copies the first file and then proceeds to produce `cannot stat` errors for the rest of the files in the list.

Why is the pipe working for the first item and failing for the rest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To integrate the other answers:

---

**TL; DR:** See below for viable solutions for `bash` and POSIX shells.

---

> Why is the pipe working for the first item and failing for the rest?

Because the shell does not behave as your command assumes it does.

The `$(ls -S | head)` Command Substitution is indeed replaced by its output, and is indeed pasted immediately adjacent to the right of the `cp specific/directory` snippet, but:

1. because you haven't double-quoted it (which is itself wrong most often than not), the Command Substitution's output undergoes Word Splitting according to the `IFS` variable; this latter is by default set to   (a single space) plus <tab> plus <newline> characters, and a <newline> happens to be what the `ls -S | head` commands use to separate each file name, hence each name ends up being a separate independent path to your `cp` command; note that in this case double-quoting the Command Substitution would not help, as you have probably found out already
2. the shell also does not duplicate the `specific/directory/` snippet for each of the names either; (that would be the job for a Brace Expansion, but it'd be tricky to get it right in this case); hence only the first one of the thus separate names gets the directory prefix and is therefore reachable by `cp`, while the other 4 names are instead expected to be present in the current directory but obviously they aren't (and even if they were, `cp` would have then complained about them being in fact the same files as the ones in the destination directory `./`)

Could it be made to "work"? in principle yes, but it'd be fragile because it'd fall apart as soon as one of the n-files contains one of the characters specified in the `IFS` variable; even worse, if combined with an uncontrolled `eval` it could be used for the most classic of command injections if you don't have full control of the filenames in `specific/directory`. (Plus, see note <sup>1</sup> below).

---

**Possible solutions for `bash` and POSIX shells**

Beside the `ls --zero` solution available when using GNU coreutils v9.0 onwards as mentioned in other answers, the operation can also be done safely<sup>1</sup> with GNU `ls` from coreutils v8.25 (circa 2016) onwards, which provides the `--quoting-style` variants for shells. For this we *need* to use `eval`, as this is in fact the only way of benefiting from that `ls` option which is indeed designed to work *with* `eval`.

As usual, `eval` needs to be handled with extra care, if ever. Here we're using it exclusively for the `ls` command only, and relying on `ls` to quote filenames correctly for the shell as per documented behavior. For additional care one may invoke for instance `/bin/ls` i.e. the explicit full path to an `ls` executable providing the wanted `--quoting-style` option instead of risking to go using who knows which `ls` happens to be in `$PATH` or perhaps who knows what exported rogue function (or even alias) purposefully named `ls`.

So, with `bash`:

```bash
(
  set -o pipefail \
    && o="$(/bin/ls -S --quoting-style=shell-escape-always | head -n 5)" \
    && eval "set -- $o" \
    && (("$#")) && cp -n -- "${@/#/specific/directory/}" .
)
```

You can easily change the number of the first n-files by changing the `head -n 5`.

Note that in the snippet above I've added extra safety and error checks, but pragmatically the whole thing can be trimmed down to the essential commands, **if** you are **absolutely positive** about your `ls` version and it having no real reason to fail or output stray characters.

```bash
(cd specific/directory && \
 eval "cp -n -- $(ls -S --quoting-style=shell-escape-always | head -n 5)"' "$OLDPWD"')
```

---

An equivalent of the above solution made for POSIX shells can also work safely<sup>1</sup> although it's not entirely ideal as it needs to load in memory the entire list of files presented by the `ls` command. As we cannot filter out such list before it gets to the shell, the source directory must not contain as many files as to fill the available memory, or else the shell will die before running the `cp` command:

```sh
(
  set -- && cd specific/directory \
    && o="$(/bin/ls -rSxw 0 --quoting-style=shell-always)" && eval "set -- $o" \
    && [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && n="$(($# - 5))" && shift "$(($n > 0 ? $n : 0))" \
    && cp -n -- "$@" "$OLDPWD"
)
```

Here you change the number of the first n-files by changing the `$(($# - 5))` bit.

Just as with the `bash` version, this one can be trimmed down a bit too, as long as you are again positive about the required pre-conditions. This one, in addition to the `bash` trimmed down version, also needs at least n-files to be **actually** present in the source directory, or else the `shift` command will fail making the shell abort prematurely (e.g. if you have less than 5 files in `specific/directory`, this trimmed down version won't copy them).

```sh
(
  set -- && cd specific/directory \
    && eval "set -- $(ls -rSxw 0 --quoting-style=shell-always)" \
    && shift "$(($# - 5))" && cp -n -- "$@" "$OLDPWD"
)
```

---

<sup>1</sup>
**NOTE:** for simplicity and explanation, the solutions above do **not** check for the files being actually *regular* files only, (i.e. not directories or symlinks, sockets, named-fifos, device files). Therefore if your source directory *does* happen to have "files" of those kinds among the first largest n-files (even if counting effectively 0 bytes), the solutions above **will** include those names in the final `cp` command. This can be particularly relevant for symlinks and directories which *always* do count greater than 0, depending on their contents, and hence may rank higher than regular files in a `ls -S`. Naturally we could loop over the filenames to test their file's types and discard the non-regular ones, but it'd get increasingly complex especially to replace the discarded ones with the next-in-rank. Please see the other answers to handle these cases sanely, as my solutions here already stretch quite a bit what `bash` and POSIX shells are capable of.

Answer (score 6):

[image: note] All my solutions treat **only files**, as requested, and **can treat all type of files**
(even with special characters).

##### If you want to use `ls -S`

do it the right way:

```
ls --zero -S | head -z -n5 | xargs -r0 cp -t ./other/dir --
```

Require recent `GNU` `coreutils`.

`coreutils 9.1-1` here.

##### Another way, using `bash` and recent `GNU` `find`:

`findutils  4.9.0-4` here.

Based [on this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/736231/sort-file-array-list-in-bash-by-date-and-bypass-argument-limit/736240#736240):

```
shopt -s nullglob
cd specific/directory/ || exit
print0 () { 
    [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\0' "$@"
}
readarray -td '' files < <(
    print0 * |
    find -files0-from - -maxdepth 0 -type f -printf '%b\t%p\0' |
    sort -rzn |
    cut -zf2 -
) 
cp -av -- "${files[@]:0:5}" "$OLDPWD"/
```

- `${files[@]:0:5}` is expanding to the first 5 elements of the **files** array whose keys are greater or equal to 0.

##### for older tools via `Perl` in any shell

```
perl -e 'rename($_, "./other/dir/$_") for ((sort { -s $b <=> -s $a } <*>))[0..4]'
```

Answer (score 6):

Using `zsh` you can avoid all the pitfalls associated with parsing and sorting the output of `ls`:

```
cp -n -- specific/directory/*(.DOL[1,5]) ./
```

or with GNU `cp` (for the `-t`option):

```
cp -n -t ./ -- specific/directory/*(.DOL[1,5])
```

where the *glob qualifiers* are

- `.` match plain files only (not directories, symlinks, fifos, sockets.)
- `D` toggle the dotglob option - omit this if you want to exclude hidden files
- `OL[1,5]` orders the results by file length (size) and selects the first 5

and the `-n` option prevents `cp` from clobbering existing files in the case of a name collision.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: New answer, works more completely:

The reason the original fails is that the directory name is added only to the first result, so the remaining results, not existing in the current directory, cause the errors re no such files.

A way that works without `find` is to take advantage of the `-F` option to `ls`, which includes trailing characters indicating the types of inodes. The following is an incomplete answer that removes directories from the listing via `grep`; a more complete answer would remove other inode types that should be excluded. The `sed` commands removes the `*` added to executables by `-F`.

```
source="<some directory name>"
destination='.'
someCount=5 # e.g.
while IFS=\  read -r; do
    cp "${source}/${REPLY}" "${destination}"
done <<<"$(ls "${source}" -Ft | grep -v '/$' | head -5 | sed 's/\*$//')"
```

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

Assume the largest files are one, two, three, and four. The command in the question ends up being

```
cp specific/directory/one two three four .
```

Since two, three, and four do not exit in ., the command fails. Something akin to

```
source=specific/directory
set -f # disable globbing
IFS='
'      # split on newlines only
for file in $(ls -S $source); do
   cp "${source}/${file}" .
done
```

would do it.

WARNING: This will break if there are any newlines in any of the file names (or if your `ls` mangles filenames even when not printing to the terminal).

Comment: Oh, do you mean my accidentally omitting the "head" command? Oops. That should be `$(ls $source | head -${someCount}`, provided someCount is set.

Comment: Thanks to [**not** parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)  + use more quotes! http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes. Moreover, you add directory when OP asked only files

Comment: Fair point re folders. Starting to look more like a job for find, re the other answer.

Comment: It occurs to me that there is another solution that doesn't require `find`, and that takes advantage of the `-F` flag to `ls`. It's convoluted, but it's an interesting hack: `while IFS=\  read -r; do cp "${source}/${REPLY}" .; done <<<"$(ls "${source}" -FS | xargs -0 | grep -v '/$' | head -${someCount} | sed 's/\*$//')"`

FWIW.

Comment: `ls | xargs -0` is a non sense. You should use `ls --zero`

Comment: Interesting. What platform are you on? AlmaLinux 9.1, RHEL 7.9, and current Mac OS all give variations of `$ ls --zero
ls: unrecognized option '--zero'`

Comment: So don't use a version of `ls` that doesn't support `--zero`.  I use `ls (GNU coreutils) 9.1`

Comment: So xargs-0 isn’t a “non sense”, then, at least not for those who may not be in a position to pull in a more recent coreutils.

Comment: Fixed that up a bit. With recent versions of GNU ls one might want to check if the output is still quoted when not printing to a terminal (I can't remember).

Comment: `xargs -0` isn't nonsense as such, not at all. But `ls | xargs -0` is a bit silly, since ls by default doesn't print any NULs. `ls --zero` plus some helpers would be a very good answer, actually. (also remember you can [edit] the answer)

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I mistakenly added that in preserving spaces, but of course it is useless for that and completely unnecessary in this case.