# Is there a maximum to bash file name expansion (globbing) and if so, what is it?

Tags: bash, wildcards, bash-expansion

Is there a maximum to bash file name expansion (globbing) and if so, what is it?
See [globbing](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html#AEN17572) on tldp.org.

Let's say I want to run a command against a subset of files:

```
grep -e bar foo*
rm -f bar*
```

Is there a limit to how many files bash will expand to, and if so what is it?

I am not looking for alternative ways to perform those operations (e.g. by using `find`).

Comment: Related: [CP: max source files number arguments for copy utility](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110282/cp-max-source-files-number-arguments-for-copy-utility)

Comment: See also: [What defines the maximum size for a command single argument?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120642/what-defines-the-maximum-size-for-a-command-single-argument) On current Linux systems, there are different limits for the size of a single argument, and for the total size. The latter depends on the stack size limit.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is no limit (other than available memory) to the number of files that may be expanded by a `bash` glob.

However when those files are passed as arguments to a command that is *executed* (as opposed to a shell builtin or function), then you may run into a limit of the `execve()` system call on some systems. On most systems, that system call has a limit on the cumulative size of the arguments and environment passed to it, and on Linux also a separate limit on the size of a single arguments.

For more details, see:

- [What defines the maximum size for a command single argument?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120642/what-defines-the-maximum-size-for-a-command-single-argument)
- [CP: max source files number arguments for copy utility](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110282/cp-max-source-files-number-arguments-for-copy-utility)

To work around that limit, you can use (assuming GNU `xargs` or compatible):

```
printf '%s\0' foo* | xargs -r0 rm -f
```

Above, since `printf` is built-in (in `bash` and most Bourne-like shells), we don't hit the `execve()` limit. And `xargs` will split the list of arguments into as many `rm` invocations as needed to avoid the `execve()` limitation.

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zargs
zargs foo* -- rm -f
```

With `ksh93`:

```
command -x rm -f foo*
```

Answer (score 8):

You can see the limit for the total size of the arguments with:

```
getconf ARG_MAX
```

This is determined generally not by the shell, but by the underlying operating system according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19355351/1421075).

Comment: I think it's the total length, not the number?

Comment: You are of course correct; I have updated my answer to reflect this.  Because of this, the limit to the number of arguments will be a function of the _length of_ the arguments.