# what is the maximum character range of grep in bash?

Tags: grep

What is the maximum character range of grep in bash? How long can a string be as input to search using the grep command?

Comment: You mean the length of a pattern, or the length of `grep` input per line or the length of arguments you type in command line?

Comment: I want to know the length of a pattern or the length of input per line. I think there can be as many arguments as possible.

Comment: What does the shell have to do with your question?

Answer (score 2):

The maximum length of the arguments to the `exec()` function (used by the shell to start a process) is defined by the value of `ARG_MAX` in the `limits.h` header. This value is also available through the `getconf` command.  On my system:

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX
262144
```

This means that the complete command line (after all variable substitutions etc. has been processed), *including any environment variables and their values*, must not exceed 256 KiB for the shell to be guaranteed to accept it.

POSIX guarantees that `ARG_MAX` is at least 4096.

For a Linux-specific discussion about `ARG_MAX`, see [Stéphane Chazelas' answer to a related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110282/cp-max-source-files-number-arguments-for-copy-utility/110301#110301).

For an in-depth discussion about this issue see https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/ (external link).

---

With `grep -f patterns file` you may bypass the maximum length of the command line by putting the patterns that you'd like to `grep` for in the file `patterns`.  The limit to the number of patterns will then be your available RAM rather than a system-imposed limit on the command line length.

Comment: Not exactly. From Linux 3.11, the `getconf ARG_MAX` reports a quarter of the limit set on the stack size, or 128 KiB if that's less than 512 KiB)

Comment: @cuonglm Is that not the real limit on such a system then?

Comment: Yes, it's not the real limit. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110301/38906

Comment: @Kusalananda -f should be the last argument just before the file name? while read line; do grep -i -w -f patterns "$line" 13April_SMILEandFINGERPRINTS.txt; done < 4804Smiles.txt >>4804matchedSMILESandFINGERPRINTS.txt because this is not working for me

Comment: If your regex is 256MB there may be additional trouble ahead, unless it's completely trivial.

Comment: Option order makes no difference.

Comment: @KHANirfan You use a file for the patterns _or_ give them on the command line. From your comment, it's unclear whether you want to match with `$line` as the pattern, or if that's the filename, and I don't know what the last file on the command line is doing there. You really have to explain what you want to be happening.

Comment: @Kusalananda $line is the pattern. It only contains tokens/records in the files. when even there is a match in the second file it is stored in output file as complete line. the last file is the output file.

Comment: @KHANirfan You should replace the loop with `grep -iw -f 4804Smiles.txt 13April_SMILEandFINGERPRINTS.txt >>4804matchedSMILESandFINGERPRINTS.txt`.  This uses `4804Smiles.txt` as the source of the patterns.

Comment: Begging for upvotes is strongly discouraged here. Please don't.