# Why not use backticks with for loop

Tags: bash, shell-script

Some time ago, I posted answer to some question about scripting. Someone pointed out that I shouldn't use following command:

```
for x in $(cat file); do something; done
```

but instead of that:

```
while read f; do something; done < file
```

[Usless Use of Cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#backticks) article suppose to explain the whole problem, but the only explanation is:

> The backticks are outright dangerous, unless you know the result of
>   the backticks is going to be less than or equal to how long a command
>   line your shell can accept. (Actually, this is a kernel limitation.
>   The constant ARG_MAX in your limits.h should tell you how much your
>   own system can take. POSIX requires ARG_MAX to be at least 4,096
>   bytes.)

If I correctly understood this, bash(?) should crash if I use output of very big file in command (it should exceed ARG_MAX define in limits.h file). So I checked ARG_MAX with command:

```
> grep ARG_MAX /usr/src/kernels/$(uname -r)/include/uapi/linux/limits.h
#define ARG_MAX       131072    /* # bytes of args + environ for exec() */
```

Then I created file containing text with no spaces:

```
> ls -l
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 100000000 Aug 21 15:37 in_file
```

Then I run:

```
for i in $(cat in_file); do echo $i; done
```

aaaand nothing terrible happened.

So what should I do to check if/how this whole 'don't use cat with loop' thing is dangerous?

Comment: When I saw your question, I thought the answer would be "use `$()` instead of backticks", but you already do.

Comment: It's not an issue of danger; it's that `for i in $(cat in_file)` doesn't iterate over the *lines* of the file, it iterates over the *words* resulting from the contents of the file being subjected to word-splitting and pathname expansion.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends what `file` is meant to contain. If it's meant to contain a IFS-separated list of shell globs like (assuming the default value of `$IFS`):

```
/var/log/*.log /var/adm/*~
/some/dir/*.txt
```

Then `for i in $(cat file)` would be the way to go. As that's what that unquoted `$(cat file)` does: apply the split+glob operator on the output of `cat file` stripped of its trailing newline characters. So it would loop over each filename resulting of the expansions of those globs (except in the cases where the globs don't match any file where that would leave the glob there but unexpanded).

If you wanted to loop over each delimited line of `file`, you'd do:

```
while IFS= read -r line <&3; do
{
  something with "$line"
} 3<&-
done 3< file
```

With a `for` loop, you could loop over every non-empty line with:

```
IFS='
' # split on newline only (actually sequences of newlines and
  # ignoring leading and trailing ones as newline is a
  # IFS whitespace character)
set -o noglob # disable the glob part of the split+glob operator:
for line in $(cat file); do
   something with "$line"
done
```

However a:

```
while read line; do
  something with "$line"
done < file
```

Makes little sense. That's [reading the content of `file` in a very convoluted way](/a/209184) where characters of `$IFS` and backslashes are treated specially.

In any case, the ARG_MAX limit the text you're quoting refers to is on the `execve()` system call (on the cumulative size of the arguments and environment variables), so only applies to cases where a command on the filesystem is being executed with the possibly very long expansion of the split+glob operator applied to the command substitution (that text is misleading and wrong on several accounts).

It would apply for instance in:

```
cat -- $(cat file) # with shell implementations where cat is not builtin
```

But not in:

```
for i in $(cat file)
```

where there's no `execve()` system call involved.

Compare:

```
bash-4.4$ echo '/*/*/*/*' > file
bash-4.4$ true $(cat file)
bash-4.4$ n=0; for f in $(cat file); do ((n++)); done; echo "$n"
523696
bash-4.4$ /bin/true $(cat file)
bash: /bin/true: Argument list too long
```

It's OK with `bash`'s `true` builtin command or the `for` loop, but not when executing `/bin/true`. Note how the `file` is just 9 bytes large but the expansion of `$(cat file)` is several megabytes because the `/*/*/*/*` glob is being expanded by the shell.

More reading at:

- [Understand "IFS= read -r line"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123)
- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)
- [CP: max source files number arguments for copy utility](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/110282)
- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346)

Answer (score 1):

[@chepner](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22257/chepner) explained the difference in comments:

> `for i in $(cat in_file)` doesn't iterate over the lines of the file, it iterates over the words resulting from the contents of the file being subjected to word-splitting and pathname expansion.

For the impact in performance and resource usage I did a small benchmark for both cases using input with 1M lines (about 19M) and measuring time and memory usage with `/usr/bin/time -v`:

**test1.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
while read x
do
    echo $x > /dev/null
done < input
```

Results:

```
Command being timed: "./test1.sh"
User time (seconds): 12.41
System time (seconds): 2.03
Percent of CPU this job got: 110%
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:13.07
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 3088
```

**test2.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
for x in $(cat input)
do
    echo $x > /dev/null
done
```

Results:

```
Command being timed: "./test2.sh"
User time (seconds): 17.19
System time (seconds): 3.13
Percent of CPU this job got: 109%
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:18.51
Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 336356
```

I've uploaded full output of both tests to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/k1VPfn0K). With bash using `for i in $(cat ...)` utilizes significantly more memory and also runs slower. However results might vary depending if you would run these same tests on some other shell.

Comment: There is also efficiency consideration. Running the loop without cat should be more efficient than running it with cat.

Answer (score -1):

`while` loops can be problematical, most notably in that they eat standard input by default (hence `ssh -n`) so if you need standard input for something else a `while` loop will fail

```
$ find . -name "*.pm" | while read f; do aspell check $f; done
$
```

does nothing as `aspell` wants a terminal which instead is occupied by a list of perl module names; a `for` loop is more suitable (assuming that the filenames won't be split by POSIX word splitting rules):

```
$ for f in $(find . -name \*.pm); do aspell check $f; done
...
```

as that does not use standard input like `while` does by default.

Also, `while` is prone to silent data loss (and `for` behaves differently for that same input):

```
$ echo -n mmm silent data loss | while read line; do echo $line; done
$ for i in $(echo -n mmm silent data loss); do echo $i; done
mmm
silent
data
loss
$
```

So arguments can be made that `while` is dangerous and should not be used, depending on the context.

Comment: I would counter all your points with `while IFS= read -r -d "" -u 3 file; do aspell check "$file"; done 3< <(find . -name "*.pm" -print0)`

Comment: That's long, not portable to `ksh`, and I can almost never remember how shell `fd` redirects work without spending a few minutes fiddling around with them.

Comment: See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Comment: @thrig None of those objections compare to "My code didn't work correctly".

Comment: If I want correct code, a shell language is extremely low on my list of choices.