# Make `xargs` use the maximum multiple of N arguments

Tags: bash, find, xargs

I have a a file that contains more than a hundred thousand of IDs. Each ID is composed of 8~16 hexadecimal digits:

```
178540899f7b40a3
6c56068d
8c45235e9c
8440809982cc
6cb8fef5e5
7aefb0a014a448f
8c47b72e1f824b
ca4e88bec
...
```

I need to find the related files in a directory tree that contains around **2×10<sup>9</sup>** files.

Given an ID like `6c56068d219144dd`, I can find its corresponding files with:

```bash
find /dir -type f -name '* 6[cC]56068[dD]219144[dD][dD] *'
```

But that takes at least two days to complete...

What I would like to do is to call `find` with as much `-o -iname GLOB` triplets as `ARG_MAX` allows.

Here's what I've thought of doing:

```bash
sed -e 's/.*/-o -iname "* & *"' ids.txt |
xargs find /dir -type f -name .
```

My problem is that I can't force `xargs` to take in only complete triplets.

How can I do it?

Comment: Apologies to the OP and to ilkkachu. I thought I knew how `xargs` worked, but I was obviously wrong.  Yet another reminder not to touch that utility again :-)

Comment: Your idea was good, just missing an additional step that I'm conceiving right now

Comment: @ilkkachu Each call takes a long time, with almost no difference with any given number of arguments; if I can do the job with the least number of calls then it would be great.

Comment: @ilkkachu That's what I wrote as an answer after analising Kusalananda idea

Comment: Thanks for editing, but please don't put placeholder text since that makes the question completely useless. It's OK, we'll wait until you have finished editing.

Comment: With the edit, this does seem like a case where `find | grep` might make sense

Comment: @muru Indeed, it seems simpler with `grep`

Comment: Similar: [Find command not working in for loop](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/703960)

Answer (score 4):

That's the wrong approach, if the point is to find all the files whose name has one of those IDs as any one of their space delimited words, then you could do:

```
find /dir -type f -print0 |
  gawk '
    !ids_processed {ids[$0]; next}
    {
      n = split(tolower($NF), words, " ")
      for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        if (words[i] in ids) {
          print
          break
        }
    }' ids.txt ids_processed=1 RS='\0' FS=/ -
```

Then you process the file list only once, and looking up the 100k ids is just a lookup in a hash table instead of doing up to 100k regex/wildcard matchings.

Comment: I've never seen `awk` being called like that, with some variables been defined  after the first file name. Where is this behaviour defined? Couldn't find it in the man, maybe I missed it. I understand what you're trying to do, which is setting some variables only after the first file is read completely, but how is this allowed? For instance, how come `awk` doesn't look for a file named `ids_processed=1` and rather treats it as new variable definition?

Comment: Ok found it: _"If a filename on the command line has the form `var=val` it is treated as a variable assignment. The variable `var` will be assigned the value `val`. (This happens after any **BEGIN block** (s) have been run.) Command line variable assignment is most useful for dynamically assigning values to the variables `AWK` uses to control how input is broken into fields and records. It is also useful for controlling state if multiple passes are needed over a single data file."_ Nice! I never knew you could do that!

Comment: Note that contrary to `-v var=value`, that was also available in the original awk from the late 70s (-v was added in nawk in the 80s). That means it can't process files whose name contains `=` characters if what's left of the first `=` is a valid awk variable name. That's why you need `awk '...' ./*.txt` instead of `awk -- '...' *.txt` for instance (you'll find several answers here mentioning this kind or problem). See also the `-E` of gawk to work around it.

Comment: excellent : much faster approach, and with lots of precise not-well-known informations, as usual for your anwsers! Thank you. (I learned about the variable interpretation in the argument list, and its workaround. Using `./files*` is anyway almost always preferable to `files*` for many usages, and is a good habit to take, as it avoids several pitfalls for many commands (ex: interpreting the characters in a filename beginning with a '-' as options for rm, etc) ). You should write a book with all the tips and "good to know" things about the shell and many utilities

Answer (score 1):

What I would do:

Write a script to save all the file names to a temporary:

```bash
# maybe run this from cron or behind inotifywait
find dir -type f -print > /tmp/filelist
```

Then do a lookup as needed using your input file:

```bash
fgrep -if hexids /tmp/filelist
```

I might suggest using `-wif` instead of `-if` but from the other comments it's not clear that you are providing accurate information in your question. `man grep` for more information.

Comment: That would look for the ids in the whole file paths, not just their (base) names.

Comment: Yes, and...? The original question appears to try to separate on word boundaries, and says all the files are in one directory. I provided the `-w` option. The sample shows a solution to the problem posted, not any other.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Kusalananda, I thought of one possible solution:

The first step is to make each `-a -b X` triplet considered as a single argument by `xargs`. Then you re-split those single-argument-triplets in an inline `sh` script and call the utility in there.

```bash
... |
awk '{ printf("%s%c", $0, 0) }' |
xargs -0 sh -c '[ "$#" -gt 0 ] && { printf %s\\n "$@" | xargs "$0" }' my_command
```

Comment: if you're on GNU, `xargs -d '\n'` would do to look at the lines as units. Or if not, `tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0` is a bit shorter than the awk. And yeah, my idea for the splitting would have been something like `sh -c 'set -f; my_command $@' _`.

Comment: Though now I do wonder if it's always safe wrt. the limit to transform the single arg `a b c` into the three `a`, `b` and `c`. If the [pointers to the arg strings count](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110301/170373) (theones passed to the `main()` of the executed program), then the effective size of the string would increase when split. Though I suppose what with the first xargs filling the available space pretty well, I guess you'd see it quickly if that issue shows up

Comment: I can't use `my_command $@` as there are spaces in the third component of the triplet; that's also the reason for using `awk`, as I can do further escaping with it

Comment: Well, in that case, I would say your example data isn't representative (I'm not also sure I'd call something with spaces a "word" in the general). There's some difference between splitting on all spaces, vs. splitting max N times, vs. handling quotes while doing it.

Comment: @ilkkachu I simplified the problem on purpose, because it isn't relevant when the splitting is done with `xargs`; also, I thought that `xargs` might have an obscure option to do the job easily.

Comment: yes, it's not relevant _if_ the splitting is done with `xargs`. But while xargs does support quotes and escaping, it does so with a syntax that's (slightly) different than e.g. the shell syntax, and there are way more tools that would lend themselves nicely to whitespace-separated inputs. Also, with questions posted on the site, it's often the case that the easiest tool to use is not the one the poster originally tried. But if the question doesn't represent the real data, it's impossible to know which tools would be valid.

Comment: Someone could have spent time working on a solution with e.g. Perl, just to have you tell them that a-ha! the data is actually different and they wasted their time. Trying to help you. For free. So yeah, please try to avoid setting up even the opportunity for that to happen. If the data is actually something like `-a -b "foo bar"`, and known to be aimed for xargs, just say it. It only needs one sentence: "The data uses quotes and escapes as interpreted by xargs".

Comment: @ilkkachu Well, such solution wouldn't help me but it would still be useful to a lot of people with simpler requirements.